# Best practice to send object array to component in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In React, suppose you have a component that is going to display a list.

Which is the more React/Redux compliant method for passing the list to the component?

1. Pass an array of objects
2. Pass an array of keys only, plus a map (dictionary) to look up the object

e.g.:

```
<ListComponent data={objectArray} />
```

vs.

```
<ListComponent keyArray={keyArray} dictionary={mapOfKeyToObject} />
```

Please consider performance, reusability, accepted conventions and testing.

thanks

EDIT:
To clarify, I mean keys as in ID fields of the objects (not talking about the keys that React uses for identifying in rendering).

The question is related to [https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#note-on-relationships]:

> > In a more complex app, you're going to want different entities to  reference each other. We suggest that you keep your state as
> >     normalized as possible, without any nesting. Keep every entity in an object stored with an ID as a key, and use IDs to reference it from 
> >     other entities, or lists. ... For example, keeping 
> >     todosById: { id -> todo } and todos: array inside the state
> >     would be a better idea in a real app.

So is it better then to pass that dictionary to the component (e.g. todosById) plus a second array with just the keys/IDs to display vs. have a subset array that's just the objects?

Consider that those objects might be getting updated by other components.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If you need an array, pass an array. I don't see any benefit of passing an object, which already has the keys, *and* an additional array of those keys. Ultimately it'll depend on how *exactly* you need to use the data. If you mean "keys" as in the keys React wants for rendering, I don't see any compelling reason to pre-generate them--that doesn't mean there *aren't* any compelling reason (like if it's hugely expensive or something?) but I've never seen that IRL.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a correct way to put object array. Instead of 2 properties you send only one.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Simply it's just:

```
function ListComponent(props) {
  const listItems = props.items.map((item) => // iterate over items array prop
    <ListItem key={item.key} value={item.value} />
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

const itemsArray = [...];
<ListComponent items={itemsArray} /> // pass array as prop
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `keyArray` isn't a prop that will be used by `ListComponent`, then it's just an overkill if you follow the second approach. First approach will be better suited if you implement the `ListComponent` to map through the array passed down as a prop.
`Array.prototype.map` function out of the box supports a key param and therefore you don't need to pass an extra key array for just display purposes, unless they are something the front end logic depends on.